# Maven Plugin for Enforcing Java File Size

Tags: java, maven

I'm looking for a plugin that will allow me, at build time, to enforce that my Java files don't exceed a certain size. For instance, if it's decided that 500 lines is too many lines for a class, then the build will fail if any classes exceed 500 lines.

For something similar, I'm thinking of [jacoco](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/) where you can configure different parameters but, of course, instead of analyzing test code coverage, it analyzes the actual number of lines in each class.

Does such a plugin exist?

Answer (score 0):

[Static code analysis (SCA) tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#Java) check things like that but I'm not aware of a Maven plugin that fails a build if such a limit is exceeded. The tools I know just create reports to inform you about such a circumstance.

Even if it existed I wouldn't use such a plugin. Too long classes are a matter of refactoring, not a matter of releasing or not working code.

Comment: Yeah, essentially some sort of SCA with a Maven plugin implementation is exactly what I'm looking for. It's unfortunate that we don't know of one.

I would disagree, though. While I probably wouldn't incorporate such a plugin in a legacy project, I think it would fit right at home on a brand new project. There are multiple plugins that break the build for things that are much less annoying, such as code style and pom sorting.

Comment: @AustinBrown Which plugins break builds due to code style or POM sorting? (Though the latter can happen with special configs but basically POMs are of declarative nature and hence sorting shouldn't matter.)

Comment: + pom sorting: https://github.com/Ekryd/sortpom/tree/master/maven-plugin
+ code style: https://github.com/coveooss/fmt-maven-plugin

Comment: @AustinBrown The `sortpom-maven-plugin`'s `verify` goal has a parameter `verifyFail=stop`. I don't see how the `fmt-maven-plugin` fails a build intentionally.

Comment: Hmm. It's possible we're having semantic misunderstandings? All I know is that with the plugin, when I try to run `mvn clean verify`, the build fails.

Comment: Misunderstandings concerning what exactly? You didn't mention in your question that you're using a plugin, you asked for one. Which of the two you mentioned in your comment fails your build? Without knowing your POM and the error msg in the build's output it's hard to tell why `mvn clean verify` fails.